# Hawking radiation from black hole inside a Casimir cavity

Tags: hawking-radiation, casimir-effect

Would a black hole inside a Casimir cavity emit Hawking radiation more slowly than a black hole outside a Casimir cavity?

Various descriptions of each phenomena involve either virtual particles or quantum wave-functions and boundary conditions.

Comment: How would you define “Casimir cavity”?

Comment: @A.V.S. Two conductive plates, parallel to each other. Is there another type of cavity? My knowledge is essentially "enthusiastic amateur".

Comment: It is not obvious how one defines “parallel planes” in a curved spacetime. But if one puts some sort of “waveguides” deep into the *thermal atmosphere* of a BH they could greatly increase the total energy lost by the BH. Conducting surfaces around rotating black hole could also greatly increase superradiant effects. On the other hand, we also can have Hawking radiation photons reflected back into the BH. So, whether such cavity would increase Hawking radiation output would depend on a lot of details: position of the planes, dof for the planes, their interaction with quantum EM fields …

Comment: I really should've thought of that point about parallel planes. Given my limited level, "it depends on XYZ" is a perfectly good answer, so thank you.